# Report Builder for the web, for integration into JavaSript (e.g. React) application

Tags: web-apps, javascript, reporting, react

There are great report building solutions for the desktop applications that have visual designers to create report layouts declaratively. I am looking similar reporting component for the JavaScript (e.g. React application). I am aware of http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html and http://pdfmake.org/playground.html and they are almost fine solutions, but I need the component with graphical builder that allow to create report visually similar how software is designed in Visual Studio of Delphi. The mentioned software pdfkit and pdfmake allows to define report textually but I am seeking component for visual definition of web report. Even the commercial https://jsreport.net/ provides only textual definition of the report.

Actually I have little hope to find software what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Report Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/reportr) can be used to display and create/edit Reports in JS/React applications with a .NET backend: [Live Sample](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/reportdesigner/defaultfunctionalities).

[React Sample Code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReactJS-1965081000.zip).

[image: Report Designer]

Reports can be exported to Word, Excel, PDF, PowerPoint and HTML.

Reports are serialized in [Report Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language) and can be created using the Report Designer (desktop or web) and the designer can be embedded in your application.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.